# Why do we need separate HW for generating the PCIe VDM/MSG Transaction?

Tags: pci-e

Though the PCIe Error reporting, Interrupt Simulation ( INTA,INTB,Etc) happens through PCIe Message Transaction, why there is a need for separate Hardware to generate the PCIe Msg/VDM Transaction?

By doing any changes in the Root-Complex driver, is it possible to create custom API's for applications to generate PCIe MSG Transaction?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: **Yes**.

I have based my answer on my understanding that if PCIe devices are moved to software and connected to a hardware root complex, there is a definite productive PCIe device prototyping in software and interactions with the real PCIe elements connected to the hardware root complex. Furthermore, we can examine the PCIe transactions at the software PCIe device without utilizing dedicated hardware system. For instance in the case of IP networks; IP network stacks at end hosts are software, however, the routers and switches are hardware.

Please check this reference [NetTLP: A Development Platform for PCIe devices in Software Interacting with Hardware](https://www.usenix.org/conference/nsdi20/presentation/kuga). It does mention a simple messaging API concept.